# How do I move Panel (Not Launcher) icons in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, dconf

I've added a couple of applets to the Ubuntu Unity top panel. How can I move them from the right side to the left side?

For example, in this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEdszm5OzFI), the person seems to have moved the Unity Panel applet "classic-menu-indicator" to the left side of the screen.

I assume dconf-editor will be involved. How can this be done for any added panel applet?

Answer (score 10):

You can't move the indicators on the panel. The video shows the 11.04 version of Unity which has the Dash button on the left side of the Unity panel (ClassicMenu Indicator just uses the same icon).

Answer (score 4):

I'll be frank, you can't. I didn't see what your were referring to in the video either.

Unity's panel is not really customizable beyond transparency (in 11.10 and up) and in how the system tray shows non-system-indicator icons. You cannot put the icons on the left.