# How do I edit the classic menu indicator

Tags: gnome, indicator, panel, menu

I installed The classic menu indicator that can be installed from ppa:diesch/testing (some really cool packages there btw).

Now I want to edit the main menu, reorganize some of the applications, make my own catergories etc.

Will installing alacarte allow me to edit this menu as I used to be able to in Gnome 2?

Also, as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89753/how-do-i-move-panel-not-launcher-icons-in-ubuntu-unity) question, how can these cool little indicators be moved across the the unity panel?

---

I refuse to install gnome-panel or gnome-session packages anymore since there appears to be too many conflicts with these and the new unity interface.

Comment: remember this site works best with one question that can be answered - try not to ask multiple questions unless they are very very similar and related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for using ClassicMenu Indicator :-)

Yes, you can use *alacarte* to edit the menu used by *ClassicMenu Indicator*. Changes may take a few seconds to become available at the indicator.

You can't move the indicators on the panel, see my answer on [the question you cited](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89753/how-do-i-move-panel-not-launcher-icons-in-ubuntu-unity).

Comment: ... hmmm... I've tried to enable/disable via alacarte in 11.10 but this doesnt affect the classic indicator :(  Enabling/disabling folders does work.  Any ideas?

Comment: @fossfreedom: Works for me. Are you using the most recent version of ClassicMenu Indicator? Please file a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/classicmenu-indicator if it doesn't work for you. Thanks.

Comment: yep - from your PPA yesterday.  I would file a bug-report, but I dont have any useful info for you other than the observation.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Please file a bug report just like that. That makes it easier for me to keep track of what issues there are, and maybe someone else can contribute more information.

Comment: At my system, alacarte was installed but not in the classic menu tree. But using alacarte (started using the gnome button, or the list of all apps in the top classicmenu item) I could enable the classicmenu section called "system settings" that contains a menu item for alacarte.