# How to rearrange the panel indicators?

Tags: unity, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I move Panel (Not Launcher) icons in Ubuntu Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89753/how-do-i-move-panel-not-launcher-icons-in-ubuntu-unity)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 x64 with Unity environment and I need to rearrange the indicators on the top panel. How can I do that?